# What cable for 200' run between camera (video/audio) and ATEM switcher

Tags: video, audio, cable, sdi

I am running a video/audio signal from a camera in a lobby to a Blackmagicdesign ATEM switcher that are about 150' apart but cable run will be closer to 200'. The video/audio from the camera in the lobby will be streamed online.
My initial design for your feedback...
Lobby will have camera with a Hollyland Mars 400S SDI/HDMI Wireless Video Transmission System. Once the signal is at the HDMI rx in the lobby it will output on an SDI port and make a 200' cable run to the Blackmagicdesign 8 port ATEM switcher.

**Lobby Camera** <--HDMI cable--> **HDMI tx** <--wireless--> **HDMI rx** with SDI output <--cable?--> **Blackmagicdesign ATEM switcher** to the live stream.

Will RG59 75ohm cable work for that 200' run or does it need to be a special "SDI" rated cable? Again, it needs to transmit both the video and audio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cable specifically designed for SDI. RG59 essentially only defines the impedance and capacitance of the cable, not the return loss and attenuation characteristics. You can use reference charts from cable manufacturers like [Belden](https://cdn.belden.com/dfsmedia/f1e38517e0cd4caa8b1acb6619890f5e/6538-source/options/download) and [Gepco](http://www.gepco.com/technical/sdi_distance_chart.htm?v=1) to select the right cable for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the response and pointing me to the manufacturer charts. That is what I needed.

Comment: Make sure you choose a cable with the right jacket, in case code in your area requires plenum or riser rated cable in the spaces you will be running it through.

Comment: Great point. I'll make sure that is part of the cable selection process. Thank you.